# Unexpected behavior of bodies affected by gravity in 2D

Tags: 2d, physics, python

I have a simple code that calculates the acceleration of a body every update of my simulation using the [Newton's law of universal gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) and [the second law of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton's_second_law).

```
def move_bodies():
    def get_dist(b1, b2):
        return math.hypot(b2['x'] - b1['x'], b2['y'] - b1['y'])

    for body in bodies:
        acceleration = 0
        angle = 0

        for other_body in bodies:
            dist = get_dist(body, other_body)

            if body != other_body:
                angle = math.atan2(other_body['y'] - body['y'], other_body['x'] - body['x'])
                acceleration = (GRAVITY_CONSTANT * body['m'] * other_body['m'] / dist ** 2) / body['m']

            body['x'] += math.cos(angle) * body['vx']
            body['vx'] += acceleration

            body['y'] += math.sin(angle) * body['vy']
            body['vy'] += acceleration
```

when these bodies interact, something unexpected happens when their x/y values are approaching one another -- the bodies move at extremely high speeds and seemingly disappear off the screen.

For example, if we have a body at (200, 100) and another at (200, 300), they do not gravitate towards one another as they would do in a situation where they have unique (x, y) values such as (200, 100) and (300, 400).

Looking at the code, as the y-values of `body` and `other_body` approach one another, values get exceedingly large(?)

I can't quite pin down the issue as I'm a beginner. Any suggestions/criticism?

Comment: Also, I am not sure that your acceleration should be the same for x and y...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on my phone and can't provide a super detailed answer, but here goes.

This answer will not cover the physics calculation that you use, only the logic.

It looks like there is trash data in your loop.

When evaluating a body with itself, you do not update the angle and the acceleration, it remeains to what was used with a previous body. Whatever is in there is still used with the body influencing itself.

I would expect that bodies don't influence themselves in that loop, so perhaps it should look a bit more like this:

```
def move_bodies():
    def get_dist(b1, b2):
        return math.hypot(b2['x'] - b1['x'], b2['y'] - b1['y'])

    for body in bodies:
        for other_body in bodies:
            if body == other_body:
                continue

            dist = get_dist(body, other_body)
            angle = math.atan2(other_body['y'] - body['y'], other_body['x'] - body['x'])
            acceleration = (GRAVITY_CONSTANT * body['m'] * other_body['m'] / dist ** 2) / body['m']

            body['x'] += math.cos(angle) * body['vx']
            body['vx'] += acceleration

            body['y'] += math.sin(angle) * body['vy']
            body['vy'] += acceleration
```

As a final note: this will most likely give inacurate results. As you update the x and the y values of bodies during the loop, you change how the next bodies are influenced by it.

A more accurate approach would be to use the "current position" to do the calculations, and to store it somewhere else for further processing:

```
def move_bodies():
    def get_dist(b1, b2):
        return math.hypot(b2['x'] - b1['x'], b2['y'] - b1['y'])

    for body in bodies:
        for other_body in bodies:
            if body == other_body:
                continue

            dist = get_dist(body, other_body)
            angle = math.atan2(other_body['y'] - body['y'], other_body['x'] - body['x'])
            acceleration = (GRAVITY_CONSTANT * body['m'] * other_body['m'] / dist ** 2) / body['m']

            body['x_sum'] += math.cos(angle) * body['vx']
            body['vx_sum'] += acceleration

            body['y_sum'] += math.sin(angle) * body['vy']
            body['vy_sum'] += acceleration

    for body in bodies:
        body['x'] = body['x_sum'] / (len(bodies) - 1)
        body['vx'] = body['vx_sum'] / (len(bodies) - 1)

        body['y'] = body['y_sum'] / (len(bodies) - 1)
        body['vy'] = body['vy_sum'] / (len(bodies) - 1)

        body['x_sum'] = 0
        body['vx_sum'] = 0

        body['y_sum'] = 0
        body['vy_sum'] = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for putting so much effort into this answer! You have corrected many of my mistakes and even taught me a little about efficient programming! Brilliant answer.

Comment: However, I am still slightly unclear with the "storing the values" method used above. The way I see it, the supposed, say, x-poses of all bodies in the system are summed. The average of this sum is then set to each body? How does this work? Again, I'm a beginner.

Comment: This approach here might not be the best for this particular situation. I'm not an expert in gravitational physics, so this average approach might be very clumsy and could require a bit more thought (like weighted values?). However the gist of it is that if you move a body during its simulation, and use this as an input during the same simulation step, the result will be kind of flawed. Simple example: if you have two bodies, A and B, and you move A influenced by B, then move B, influenced by A, the influence received by B will be tainted by the calculations made on A.

Comment: This means that checking A before B will not result in the same output as if you checked B before A. (I guess this could amplify some effects? I don't know.)

Comment: I guess appending to a list would suffice?

Comment: I'm not sure I actually answered your question ;P In this case, each body gets its own average. As stated above, that might not be the right calculation to do, you'll probably need to figure this out. Maybe you actually need the `x_sum` added to the current `x`? I'm not too sure about this. The idea here is really to have the calculation made on the "current x" for all of the "other bodies", so that all of the "other bodies" see the same x value; then you apply the different forces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102702/discussion-between-vaillancourt-and-sean-xie).